# Autocomplete input from api rest get methot

Tags: javascript, rest, web, service

I'm trying to autocomplete a form using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#input_15').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
         $.getJSON("ws_ServicioCLOUD/Consulta.aspx?cedula=" + request.term, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                console.log(value);
                return {
                    label: value.label,
                    value: value.value
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 100
});
    </script>
```

Student Name :

```
{"empleado":[{"CEDULA":"111111111","NOMBRES":"VICENTE RAMIRO","APELLIDOS":"BANEGAS GUERRERO","EMAIL":"correo@correo.com"]}
```

So is not showing noting and when I try complete someting I'm getting and Object error.

Comment: what you are getting in console? If nothing then check your service

Comment: I dont know how to check the console, the web service is sending me the correct values

Comment: Just press F12 in your browser and refresh your page then go to console tab to see what's there

Comment: its empty.. just I see >

Comment: that means your ` $.getJSON` call is not working, can you try to put your code under `ready` function

Comment: I'm using this links in the header:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
where is the ready function?

Comment: add it like this `$(document).ready(function(){$('#input_15').autocomplete({` and close it after your autocomplete function `})`

Comment: I'm getting this error: Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'

Comment: seems like you are calling http service from https page. add this line in your page head tag and try again `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Comment: Great so now I'm getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. so I need to create an ssl?

Comment: I think so.....